# Option not being disabled when I use optionsCaption

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to disable options in a combobox with knockout.js. In [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) there is one example:

`<select data-bind="
    options: myItems,
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsValue: 'id',

    optionsAfterRender: setOptionDisable">
</select>`

`var vm = {
      myItems: [{
        name: 'Item 1',
        id: 1,
        disable: ko.observable(false)
      }, {
        name: 'Item 3',
        id: 3,
        disable: ko.observable(true)
      }, {
        name: 'Item 4',
        id: 4,
        disable: ko.observable(false)
      }],
      setOptionDisable: function(option, item) {
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {
          disable: item.disable
        }, item);
      }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(vm);`

It works well. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/afLtgszk/7/) is the JSFiddle.

But when I add `optionsCaption`, bindings are not working, and only caption is shown in combobox. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/afLtgszk/8/) is the JS Fiddle with captionsOption.

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When knockout inserts a caption, it uses the value `undefined` for the option that shows the caption.

This means that, in your after render, you'll get the first item as `undefined`. Since you cannot apply the data-bind `disable: undefined.disable`, it will throw an error.

You'll need an extra check to prevent knockout from trying to bind to `undefined`s `disable` property:

```
setOptionDisable: function(option, item) {
  if (!item) return;
  ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {
    disable: item.disable
  }, item);
}
```